# Remove class on click

Tags: jquery, click, addclass, removeclass

I have a problem with removing classes with jquery.

I wanted to add and remove a class on click on the class but it doesn't work. Why?

```
$('.class').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("class1");
    $(this).removeClass("class");
});
```

The hide function works fine (also $(this).hide()) but the image changing not works after that:

```
$('.class').mouseenter(function() {
    jQuery(this).attr("src", 'icons/heart.png');
}).mouseleave(function() {
    jQuery(this).attr("src", 'icons/heart_disabled.png' );
});

$('.class1').mouseenter(function() {
    jQuery(this).attr("src", 'icons/heart_disabled.png');
}).mouseleave(function() {
    jQuery(this).attr("src", 'icons/heart.png' );
});
```

so I think the class not changed.

Comment: Missing document ready handler?

Comment: That should totally work!

Comment: Unless of course you're binding it before the DOM is ready as undefined said.

Comment: or if there's a typo in the class name

Comment: Summarizing: We need more information to usefully help you with this. :-)

Comment: or if the class itself is added dynamically - which seems to be the case.

Comment: I'm not forget the ready handler, and the class is not work dynamically.

Comment: Or if there's another handler that executes sooner and returns false (or stops immediate propagation)

Comment: or if a thrown exception prevents the click handler to be attached

Comment: or if jQuery itself is not present

Comment: I added more Information, thanks.

Comment: Try `$(document).on('click','.class',function(){...})` instead of `$('.class').click(function(){...})`. That covers my best guess about why your code could be failing.

Comment: sorry @Jan Dvorak , thats not work too

Comment: The information you've added reduces the set of failure modes slightly, but there's nothing that could cause the issue you're describing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should delegate the events, event handlers are bound to the elements not class names, that's why you think that classes are not added/removed, try the following:

```
$(document).on({
   mouseenter: function() {
      this.src = 'icons/heart.png';
   },
   mouseleave: function() {
      this.src = 'icons/heart_disabled.png';
   }
}, 'img.class');

$(document).on({
   mouseenter: function() {
      this.src = 'icons/heart_disabled.png';
   },
   mouseleave: function() {
      this.src = 'icons/heart.png';
  }
}, 'img.class1');
```